# MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 upgrade causes significant write slowdown (MyISAM + indexes)

Tags: mysql, myisam, indexing

We just upgraded from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5. An insert script that used to take ~3 mins to insert ~200k rows into a MyISAM table with 3 indexes now takes ~8 mins! Removing the indexes solves the issue!?

Reads(selects) are fine (faster in 5.5 than 5.1)

Is something different about index behavior or could there be some oddball config parameter that may need to be tweaked?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

### System Info:

Fedora 17, Mysql 5.5.29-log, 16GB RAM

MyISAM Key Buffer = 4GB

MyISAM index size = ~800 MB

MyISAM table size = 4.4 GB

INNODB Buffer Pool = 8GB

INNODB table+index size =  ~12GB

- Here's the table definition per request:

CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE`

(  `MY_TABLE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `FIELD_1` char(1) NOT NULL,
   `FIELD_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `FIELD_3` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   `FIELD_4` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_5` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_6` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_7` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_8` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_9` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_10` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_11` varchar(124) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_12` varchar(124) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_13` varchar(124) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_14` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_15` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_16` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_17` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_18` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_19` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_20` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_21` text,
   `FIELD_22` text,
   `FIELD_23` text,
   `FIELD_24` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_25` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_26` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_27` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_28` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_29` text,
   `FIELD_30` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `FIELD_31` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FIELD_32` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CREATION_DATE` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `MODIFICATION_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`MY_TABLE_ID`),
   KEY `I_FIELD_4` (`FIELD_4`),
   KEY `I_FIELD_2` (`FIELD_2`),
   KEY `I_FIELD_3` (`FIELD_3`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Are you now using the default InnoDB engine?

Comment: Not sure I am following your question. The table is MyISAM (as described in original post).

Comment: The previous post describes the original set up. Consider providing a 'SHOW CREATE table'.

Comment: Just added table definition per request

Comment: Thinking out loud, before delving too far into this, I see that MySQL now has a 5.6 release candidate (and MariaDB also has a 5.6 equivalent). Before you go tweaking settings, I just wonder if it would be possible to stick one of these on another box somewhere and see if your problem miraculously disappears?

Comment: Moving to 5.6 is not an option at this point. Way too new. I don't think its even production ready yet. In fact we are very concerned about our move to 5.5 right now. 5.1 was working fine for us.

Comment: I can't see why the move to 5.5 should cause this. This only thing I can think is to explore using optimize table dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Tables are optimized as part of the write jobs...removed and re-inserted indexes as well. Problem is across the board on various tables..

Answer (score 0):

Well, after lots of troubleshooting, the issue was narrowed down to bad drives. Not MySQL 5.5. Everything is fine now with different drives..

Answer (score 0):

RAM is too crowded.

For 16GB RAM and a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM:

```
key_buffer_size = 1600M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
```